# How to find the impulse response of a discrete system in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, ifft

I have a discrete system where the input is `x_n` and the output is `y_n` now I want to calculate the impulse response of this system, that is I want to find the output of the system when the input is `[1,0,...,0]`. 
for my example when:

`x_n = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];` then `y_n = [0,0.1,0.3,0.5,0.4,0.7,0.3,0.5];`

I have already tried: (I'm not sure if this correct)

```
X = fft(x_n);
Y = fft(y_n);
Impulse_response = ifft(Y/X);
```

Is there any other method to find the impulse response?

Comment: You're over-thinking it - just set X equal to a unit impulse and then the output Y will be the impulse response (by definition). You don't need to do any frequency domain stuff with FFTs.

Comment: I know but I don't have the transfer function how can I set X to unit impulse? @Paul

Comment: Oh - you said you "have a discrete system" - I took that to mean that you have a discrete system that you could apply an input to. So do you just have this one input/output data set ?

Comment: Yes I've just got this one. @Paul

Comment: OK - this comes under the general topic of [deconvolution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution). For a simple example like this, with (presumably) no noise, you can just use the method you describe (for real world examples it gets more complicated). Make sure you pad X with zeroes first though, to make it is the same length as Y.